# What to use in translating a website into other languages?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-translate

I'm having a problem with automatic translating of website into other languages? I'm using google app engine as a platform and php as the language.I already read the translate API, but it cannot translate the whole page. The error message is "url is too long to process". I also tried this https://translate.google.com/manager/website/add but there is a dropdown to achieve the translation. Is there a way to automatically translate the website?

What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: What is the purpose of cURL on this? Your comment is not descriptive. Not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

> url is too long to process

Means that you are using GET to get the translations and request you are sending is too big because GET methods are limited to a specific length for the request. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request) for more info.

The translation API supports as most APIS do, **the POST method**.

Change the method that you request the translations with POST. Probably that is what @daan was talking about.

Comment: Thanks.. I'll try this tommorow. Daan answer is not descriptive. It will confuse the viewer of this question.

Comment: @Imat should solve the too long url. The translation API works fine with GAE. Also try not to translate the whole page content, but if possible split it into small parts. Not too many to increase the overhead.